# how to get file path from intent data uri

Tags: java, android, react-native, flutter, kotlin

I'm using intent to select a video,

```
fun openVideo(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        intent.type = "video/*"
        startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),
            REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO
        )
}
```

then i'm getting uri and path

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO && data != null) {

            val videPath = data.data?.path 
            val selectedVideoUri: Uri? = data!!.data.toString()
        }
    }
```

output

```
videPath:
/external_files/KannadaGeeta/05CHAPTER2.mp3

selectedVideoUri :
content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/KannadaGeeta/05CHAPTER2.mp3
```

but I need path like below to check whether file exist or not

```
/storage/emulated/0/KannadaGeeta/13CHAPTER12.mp3
```

Look, by working on strings I can achieve what I want. But I'm looking for a proper way to get the video path.

Can anyone help me on this.

Edit:

i tried this which is giving false

```
File(selectedVideoUri).exists()
```

Comment: You do not have to check if the file exists. If the file did not exist the user could not have picked it.

Comment: You should save `selectedVideoUri` in your database.

Comment: You realise that `videPath` is only the last piece of that content scheme?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with 'i do not want to work on strings'. A path is a string too isnt it?

Comment: You do not have to format anything. And you should not try to convert an uri -a nice content scheme- to a file system path. As a professional you should use the obtained uri directly. What is the reason you want a path? That uri is all you need.

Comment: It looks as if you would become a big friend of functions like getRealPathFromUri(). Just google for them, there are plenty. But it will only help you below Q. For Q an R they are pretty useless and as a professional you want to be ready for now and the future...

Comment: You can check using the uri. No need for a path.

Comment: Well it is possible. Otherwise i would not have said such. Please show the used code in your post. Dont use a comment for it.

Comment: You cannot use the File class for a content scheme. The File class can only be used for a file system path.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace the `/external_files` with the external directory.

```
 val intentPath = activity?.intent!!.data!!.path!!

 val absolutePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + intentPath.substringAfter("/external_files") 

 e.g

 println("Intent Path : ${intentPath}")
 // Intent Path : external_files/KannadaGeeta/05CHAPTER2.mp3

 println("Absolute Path : ${absolutePath}")
 // Absolute Path : /storage/emulated/0/KannadaGeeta/05CHAPTER2.mp3
```

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question "Look, by working on strings I can achieve what I want. But I'm looking for a proper way to get the video path."